# retrieving items disregarded by a table join?

Tags: mysql

I have two mysql tables. `ItemTable` which is simple an item-id and some item related data.

```
 --------------------------------------
| ItemId | ItemDescription | ItemPrice |
 --------------------------------------
```

I have another table `CategoryTable` that is responsible for categorizing the items into different categories

```
  --------------------------------------
| ItemId | CategoryId                   |
 ---------------------------------------
```

Not all items are categorized. What is the fastest/most-efficient way to find an uncategorized item (by its id) without changing the schemas of the two tables. I tried joining the two tables on `ItemId` but it disregards the uncategorized items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select the `ItemIds` from the `CategoryTable`, and then select those ids in `ItemTable` that are not in `CategoryTable`.

```
SELECT ItemId
FROM ItemTable
WHERE ItemId NOT IN (SELECT C.ItemId
                     FROM CategoryTable C);
```

If you want every `ItemId` and its `Category`, and also include those items that have no category, you can use `LEFT JOIN`. This will output `NULL` for the `Category` field of uncategorized items.

```
SELECT I.ItemId, C.Category
FROM ItemTable I
LEFT JOIN CategoryTable C
ON I.ItemId = C.ItemId;
```